# App Crashed when Tableview transition from RootCtrl to DetailCtrl iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, crash, tableview

In my iphone app, I created manually my tableview, that i insert in a view.

I used this Code to Make my transition :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {

DetailViewController *dvController = [DetailViewController alloc];
dvController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:dvController animated:YES];

[dvController release];
dvController = nil;
}
```

And my error is : 
    Thread 1 : program received signal: 'SIGABRT' 
The error is fixed on main.m :

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Someone could help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
```